# Username in url but following context path with '/'?

Tags: url, jakarta-ee, jquery, url-rewriting, urlencode

I am developing an Online Recruitment System in **Java EE** using *Servlets* and I want to give each user his own unique url by adding username to context path using **'/'**.

Simply put I want to rewrite my url from **/main** to **/main/username** so when people login they can see their username in address bar(just like at stackoverflow or facebook).

Eg. Currently I am redirecting to **"/main?username="+username** (works fine) using *Jquery Ajax* but I want to redirect to **/main/username**.
I tried *encodeURL method* but '/' makes search for into subdirectory. If anybody think it should work, please give me the syntax.
I have done url mapping in *web.xml*.(Eg. signin.jsp is mapped to *signin* uri)

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question concisely if you described the actual problem you're encountering more clearly. I'll give it a try, but if i'm off the mark, then try adding more detail to the problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to have a Java EE site like `myrecruitingsite.com` where you can redirect a user to `myrecruitingsite.com/main/<username>`.  When a request is made to `myrecruitingsite.com/main/arg21`, or `myrecruitingsite.com/main/geoffreywiseman`, you'd want the request to go to the same servlet, and you'd like to know which username was requested.

Java servlet mappings don't directly support complex routing patterns in the way that many modern web frameworks do. You can't configure the web.xml to send a request from `myrecruitingsite.com/main/<username>` to the user profile servlet and `myrecruitingsite.com/main/<username>/contact` to the contact servlet. You can do wildcard mappings, but all the routing decisions after that you'll have to do outside of the `web.xml`.

Alternately, you can do [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) (typically with servlet filters) such that the URL requested by the browser is not the final one interpreted by the servlet mapping layer. There are frameworks for this, or you can do it yourself.

Basically, you need to configure the [servlet mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html)'s url pattern with a wildcard, and then query  [getPathInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) to find out what the rest of the wildcard was. That alone is pretty simple.

If you're using any one of a wide array of Java web frameworks, there will be facilities for routing and quite possibly a front controller servlet that does what you need already. In that scenario, you'll need to look at the framework's documentation for more information.

On the other hand, if you're doing it yourself using servlets (or even servlets + jsp), you can either just do a wildcard mapping to a single servlet that will grow larger and larger as you add more features to it, or more likely, you'll need to develop your own micro-framework where the servlet acts as a [Front Controller servlet](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) and does the routing work and delegates all the subsequent work to plain old java objects (POJOs).

By way of example, your routing servlet could maintain a mapping between url patterns (perhaps specified in java regular expressions) to objects of your own creation that either mimic the servlet interface or another interface of your own creation. That way, you have a servlet that's responsible for the routing decisions bound in the web.xml, and a network of little classes that are responsible for the specifics of a particular request. It's work, but it's not terrifically difficult.

Comment: I am not using any framework and I am using only servlets. Can you give me a brief idea on what to do in the Front Controller servlet?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is achieved using url rewrites on the server. For IIS that means creating a web.config or in apache creating a .htaccess file. You'll need to find the equivalent for your server and it can then be made to parse the directory structure type /username/ into a HTTP GET variable for your application.